# How to use handleChange in react-numpad widget?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

This is my react-numpad widget I created:

```
const state = {
  number: 0
};

//MAYBE the three following lines are wrong. How to use handleChhange in react-numpad?
const handleChange = e => {
  this.setState(e.target.value);
};

const handleBlur = e => {
  if (e.target.value === "0") e.target.value = "0";
};

const handleKeypress = e => {
  const characterCode = e.key;
  if (characterCode === "Backspace") return;

  const characterNumber = Number(characterCode);
  if (characterNumber < 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};

const myTheme = {
  fontFamily: "Arial",
  textAlign: "center",
  header: {
    primaryColor: "#263238",
    secondaryColor: "#f9f9f9",
    highlightColor: "#FFC107",
    backgroundColor: "#607D8B"
  },
  body: {
    primaryColor: "#263238",
    secondaryColor: "#32a5f2",
    highlightColor: "#FFC107",
    backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9"
  },
  panel: {
    backgroundColor: "#CFD8DC"
  }
};

const priceWidget = ({
  step,
  precision,
  input,
  placeholder,
  label,
  theme,
  props,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
      <NumPad.Number
        {...rest}
        step={0.1}
        precision={2}
        placeholder={!input.value ? "please, type a number" : input.value}
        selected={input.value ? new NumPad.Number(input.value) : null}
        onKeyDown={changedVal => handleKeypress(changedVal)}
        onBlur={changedVal => handleBlur(changedVal)}
        //IN the FOLLOWING LINE it doesn't work
        onChange={value => handleChange(value)}
        //BUT IN THIS ONE FOLLOWING LINE WORKS FINE but the field doesn't get the setted value
        // onChange={(value) => console.log("price's value",value)}
        //ISSUE theme= {myTheme}
        //ISSUE  onChange={input.onChange}
        //ISSUE  onBlur={input.onBlur}

        className="form-control"
      />
      <div className="text-danger" style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
        {touched && error}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default priceWidget;
```

When I'm executing this line:

```
onChange={(value) => handleChange(value)}
```

I've got following issue:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**

But when I'm executing this another line:

`onChange={(value) => console.log("price's value",value)}`

It works fine but the field doesn't update with value I selected from my numpad.

e.g. I selected 44 when I'm executing this line:

`onChange={(value) => console.log("price's value",value)}`
and shows value on console but the field from numpad doesn't update nor show the selected value. It's empty.

So, I have to use handleChange method to change input value but it's not well- implemented.

How can I solve this issue?, anyone knows how can I fix this issue?

Comment: const handleChange = (e) =>{
                 this.setState({number:e.target.value});
                 }

Comment: you are not specifying which state is to be updated

Comment: It doesn't work. I've got the same issue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined          Probably I don't specify the state, but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: can you create a sandbox and mention the link?

Comment: Here is: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-goldstine-xy14j                                               please, see App.js is not inside src. There is the code I need you watch.

Comment: code not there. save and check in incognito before sending

Comment: try again. I removed the App.js It's predeterminate and replaced by App.js I wrote code.

Comment: Go to this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-goldstine-xy14j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that App component is a functional component. So `this.setState` way of updating the state will not work. You will have to use `useState` hook.

For more information - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html